# I want to remove the div container always when click submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form from i am getting values. Like this.

```
<form role="form" id="calculate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="paper">
                        <option value="0">Type of the Paper</option>
                        <option value="0.002252">Createspace White Paper</option>
                        <option value="0.0025">Createspace Cream Paper</option>
                        <option value="0.002347">Createspace Color-Interior Books&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value="0.002252">Lulu Standard</option>
                        <option value="0.00260">Lulu Standard Publisher</option>
                        <option value="0.001943"></option>
                        <option value="0.003953">135# (200gsm)</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pages" placeholder="Number of Pages">

                    <select class="form-control" id="print">
                        <option value="0">Type of Printing</option>
                        <option value="0.03937">Soft Cover</option>
                        <option value="0.07874">Paperback</option>
                        <option value="0.15748">Hard Cover</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="calbutton"><input id="mybtn" type="button" onclick="up()"/></div>
            </form>
```

When user click at the button, it will goto the function with the name of up. See below.

```
function up(){
    var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {value:0.000,pace:6000, auto:false});

    var print = document.getElementById("print").value; 
    //alert(print);
    var paper = document.getElementById("paper").value; 
    //alert(paper);
    var pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;
    //alert(pages);

    ans = parseFloat(paper) * parseFloat(pages) + parseFloat(print);
    var val = ans.toFixed(3);

    //alert(val);

        if(pages == ""){
        alert("Please Enter Number of Pages");

        }else{
            var x=parseFloat(val);
            //$("#flip-counter").html(x);
             //alert (x);

            var roundoff=(val*25.4).toFixed(2);
            $("#mm").html("<p class='text-center'>"+roundoff+" mm</p>");
            //alert();
            myCounter.setValue(x);
            return false;
            //document.getElementById("calculate").reset();
        //  myCounter.incrementTo(val, 2, 200);

        }

    //myCounter.setValue(1245);

}
```

The problem is that when i click at the button, it will works fine and place the counter value in this div within the 4 different  un order lists .

When again i click at the button, i will again generate 4 more un order lists, and don't overwrite the old one.
I want that when user again click at the button this div again come to the original form and remove all present un order lists. like this

Can any one help me? i need your help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle highlighting this issue? It would make it easier to work on.

Comment: When i click at the button they show me counter value in this structure.

Comment: When i click at the button they show me counter value in this structure.
<div class="flip-counter" id="flip-counter">
<ul class="cd" id="flip-counter_d2"><li id="flip-counter_b_d2" class="b"></li></ul><ul class="cd" id="flip-counter_d1"><li id="flip-counter_b_d1" class="b"></li></ul>
</div>
When i again click at the button i will again generate more uls, i but i want to first remove all old uls and structure like this

<div id="flip-counter" class="flip-counter"></div>

than place a new counter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following in the first line of your up function to remove the previous unordered list.

```
var parentEl = $("#flip-counter").parent();
parentEl.find("#flip-counter").remove();
```

or

```
$('body').find("#flip-counter").remove();//this will remove the division itself
```

replace $('body') with the parent element of flip counter division.To remove only the ul present inside the division use

```
$('body').find("#flip-counter > ul").remove();//this will remove only the ul inside the division
```

Comment: There's nothing indicating he uses JQuery

Comment: $("#mm") with this line I assume he is using jquery.

Comment: Thanks alot "Rajesh Madhu". It works, you are awesome.

Comment: Super.I am working on java script thinking you aren't using jQuery.

Comment: I don't have reputation and for vote up required repotation is 15. :(